# Diferencias entre variables timeout

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

estoy trabajando con una aplicación web que en código realiza un `Session.Timeout = 30`, y es esta parte la que me confunde, ya que en el `web.config` se tienen las siguientes configuraciones:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms defaultUrl="Login.aspx" loginUrl="Login.aspx" name="AuthenticationAgeAdmin" protection="None" timeout="60"/>
</authentication>

<sessionState mode="InProc" timeout="60" cookieName="nombreCookie"/>
```

Que diferencia hay entre las diferentes configuraciones y lo que se hace en código y cual sería la mejor forma de configurar estos tiempos.

He estado leyendo algunos casos que reportan problemas con TimeOut pero no logro entender estas diferencias.

Answer (score 1):

El timeout para formulario indica cuanto tiempo va a durar el cookie antes de expirarse. Mientras que el timeout para `sessionState` indica el tiempo que dura un valor en memoria antes de ser reciclado y eliminado. Por ejemplo, puedes estar autenticado por la session del cookie pero al momento de obtener la data de la session, puedes encontrar null debido al reciclado de la memoria por `InProc`.

Nota: Mensiono que guarda la data de la session en memoria porque utilizas `InProc`. Existen varias maneras de guardar los datos de session. [Puedes leerlo en la documentacion oficial](https://www.google.com.do/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0ahUKEwiO1MiLxfHXAhUDwiYKHRptDSIQFggnMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Flibrary%2Fms178586.aspx&usg=AOvVaw0gV90SmktyGYS7f7TIm4h0)

Comment: Gracias por su respuesta, ¿Y cuando por código se realiza un `Session.Timeout = x` Esto es equivalente a alguno de los dos que mencionas o es diferente?